# Inter project dependencies in IAR

Tags: iar

Is there anyway to specify dependencies between projects in a IAR workspace? Say you have projects A and B, and A builds a library that B links. Can you force IAR to build A any time you build B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a batch build, that builds several projects in the order you want